# Replace char '/' in python

Tags: python, string

I have to replace in a string the character '/' with '\' I use

`str.replace('/','\')`

but got this error:

Lexical error at line..., column ....  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\'` is used for escape sequences so if you want to use it you have to escape that character:

```
str.replace('/','\\')
```

See the [python documentation on string literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash has a [special meaning](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) in strings. Use `'\\'` instead.

Comment: but it will throw SyntaxError, not LexicalError, right?

Comment: @mu無: On Jython: "SyntaxError: Lexical error at ..."

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [Escape Sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)

```
>>> m="hell/o"
>>> k=m.replace('/','\\')
>>> print k
hell\o
```